# DotNet CLI doesn't check any package repositories during install so all package installs fail?

Tags: .net

I have DotNet 5.x installed on Windows 10.  However, when I try to install **any** packages using the *dotnet* CLI, I get the same error, even commonly known ones that many people use:

```
C:\Users\robert>dotnet tool install --global dotnet-cowsay --version 1.3.0
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-cowsay (>= 1.3.0)' for 'net5.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-cowsay (>= 1.3.0)' for 'net5.0/any'
```

Well this is weird.  I did a verbose dump of the "dotnet" install process of "cowsay" on my Windows 10 PC where the command is failing, and did the same on my Windows 8.1 that *was *able to install *cowsay* successfully.  In the successful log the utility makes two URL requests for the package and I see the URLs in the log.  In the failed log *those requests are never made*, in fact the utility doesn't make *any* requests at all!  I tried adding a specific Windows Defender entry for the "dotnet" utility (i.e. - ".NET Host") with Private and Public network access both allowed on the Windows 10 PC, but that didn't help.  Something is interfering with that utility access the Web.

Successful log:

```
  Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0...
           GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='dotnet-cowsay'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
           OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='dotnet-cowsay'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 1102ms
           GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/dotnet-cowsay/1.3.0
           OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/dotnet-cowsay/1.3.0 865ms
         Resolving conflicts for net5.0...
```

Failed Log:

```
    Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0...
         Resolving conflicts for net5.0...
```

Does anyone know if the "dotnet" utility shells to some other process/utility to do its Web access work (e.g. - Curl, etc.).  If so,  what is the name of that entity, so I can try adding a firewall entry for it too?

What is wrong with my installation and how can I fix it?  I have Visual Studio Code and VS2017 and many other applications installed and they all work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I had to take to fix my problem:

- Completely uninstall ALL versions of the .NET framework, runtimes and SDKs, using the Control Panel (11 entries in total)
- Delete the Nuget sub-directory in the %appdata%  directory
- Restart the system
- Install .NET 5.x again from scratch

Now the dotnet/nuget package install operations work.

Comment: Seriously MS? I can confirm this is the only thing that worked for me. I tried installing the latest dotnet 5, then removed the appdir, still didn't work. I had to follow these steps exactly.